# hibernate hbm2ddl boolean column typeCastException in dbunit

Tags: hibernate, exception, casting, derby, dbunit

I use an in memory Derby database with Hibernate to create the tables. My tests use dbunit to prepare the database with test data.

```
db.driverClass=org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
db.url=jdbc:derby:memory:myDb;create=true
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop
```

Hibernate seems to create a smallint column type to store a boolean value. But dbunit cannot convert this value.

```
Caused by: org.dbunit.dataset.datatype.TypeCastException: Unable to typecast value <true> of type <java.lang.String> to SMALLINT
```

Any idea to make Hibernate create a boolean column (if available in derby) or to make dbunit write java boolean to the smallint column?

This explains the same issue, but there seems to be no DataTypeFactory implementation for Derby. http://old.nabble.com/Data-type-factory-for-Derby-database.-td25996976.html

Comment: i have the same problem with oracle, did you find a solution to allow dbunit to interpret booleans according to the underlying db implementation?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe a true boolean datatype is currently available in Derby, although there is work underway to provide one, see: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DERBY-4716. A Derby release supporting that work is expected "soon".